# remove a <tr> element by clicking a button on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using Jquery to add a table row into an existing table. The  I'm adding has two columns. One simple string, the other has a small button. I'd like a click on the button to remove its parent  element in the most elegant way, ideally without calling an external JS function. IS that possible?

Comment: Can you show some example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        This is Item 1
      </td>
      <td>
        This is still Item 1
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="remove">This is Button 1</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        This is Item 2
      </td>
      <td>
        This is still Item 2
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="remove">This is Button 2</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        This is Item 3
      </td>
      <td>
        This is still Item 3
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="remove">This is Button 3</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        This is Item 4
      </td>
      <td>
        This is still Item 4
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="remove">This is Button 4</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

just use [.closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest) and [.remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove) in the click handler for the button

```
jQuery(this).closest('tr').remove()
```

`closest` will find the closest parent element matching the passed selector, and `remove` as the name implies will remove it.

And since you say you are adding the rows to an existing table you can use delegation to deal with new rows and not have to add new click listeners every time you add a new row.

```
jQuery(document).on("click",".removeBtn",function(){
   jQuery(this).closest('tr').remove()
});
```

Demo

```js
jQuery(".removeBtn").click(function(){
  jQuery(this).closest("tr").remove();  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Sample row</td>
    <td><button class="removeBtn">Remove</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sample row 2</td>
    <td><button class="removeBtn">Remove</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sample row 3</td>
    <td><button class="removeBtn">Remove</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```